# Writing files in Google Cloud using PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, phpexcel, phppowerpoint

So I am trying to write a PPT file using PHP in my Google Cloud App Engine.

The final code to write the file is

```
$xmlWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpPresentation, "PowerPoint2007");
$xmlWriter->save("php://output");
```

It is workng in my Localhost but when I deploy it to google cloud it gives the error `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` in google chrome and `File Not Found` in mozilla firefox.

When i accessed the logs it says

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file vfs://root/temp/.//phppttmp569a45e921e8a8.63056743.' in /base/data/home/apps/s~frrolefrontend/mediascout:ms-080.390023055217794078/mediascout/ppt_export/src/PhpPresentation/Writer/PowerPoint2007.php:320
Stack trace:
#0 /base/data/home/apps/s~frrolefrontend/mediascout:ms-080.390023055217794078/mediascout/ppt_export/samples/Sample_Header.php(72): PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Writer\PowerPoint2007->save('php://output')
#1 /base/data/home/apps/s~frrolefrontend/mediascout:ms-080.390023055217794078/mediascout/ppt_export/samples/scout_temp.php(381): write(Object(PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\PhpPresentation), 'scout_temp', Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /base/data/home/apps/s~frrolefrontend/mediascout:ms-080.390023055217794078/mediascout/ppt_export/src/PhpPresentation/Writer/PowerPoint2007.php on line 320
```

After doing some research i found that `Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file` is because the directory is not writable.

Can you tell me how can i make a directory in App Engine Writable?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Appengine Apps doesn't have write access to filesystem. From docs:

> The sandbox isolates your application for reliability, scalability and
>   security. For this reason, a small number of PHP functions are not
>   available on App Engine, and others will raise an exception if used
>   incorrectly. For instance, an app cannot write data to the local file
>   system. Instead, apps can use scalable services provided by Google to
>   store and process data and communicate over the Internet.

(from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/features/)

You have to use Google Cloud Storage bucket to write files:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('gs://my_bucket/hello.txt', 'Hello');
```

There're some examples https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/

Comment: I tried doing it but it is also giving me the same error.

Comment: Can you tell me what configuration do I need to make to make it work? I created a bucket. Used the url and it is not working.

Comment: did you get file in the bucket? were you able to write using simple file, not a powerpoint file?